# PHP-CS-Fixer fix in precommit hook but file doesn't add to commit

Tags: php, git, bash, pre-commit, php-cs-fixer

I want to automatically fix files with php-cs-fixer before commit and then commit changes including this fixes

So I created pre-commit file, but I have problems:

1) I can't get know which file was changed (maybe just a bash problem)

2) If I run "git add" without condition, changes are included to commit, but not the files itself

I've tried to show it clearily in the comments of the hook, so here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# get the list of changed files
staged_files=$(git diff --cached --name-only)

# command to fix files
cmd='vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix %s -q'
if [ -f 'php_cs_fixer_rules.php' ]; then
    cmd='vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix %s -q --config=php_cs_fixer_rules.php'
fi

for staged in ${staged_files}; do # this cycle exactly works
    # work only with existing files
    if [[ -f ${staged} && ${staged} == *.php ]]; then # this condition exactly works
        # use php-cs-fixer and get flag of correction
        eval '$(printf "$cmd" "$staged")' # this command exactly works and corrects the file
        correction_code=$? # but this doesn't work

        # if fixer fixed the file
        if [[ ${correction_code} -eq 1 ]]; then #accordingly this condition never works
            $(git add "$staged") # even if the code goes here, then all changes will go into the commit, but the file itself will still be listed as an altered
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0 # do commit
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Especially I want to know why correction_code doesn't get value and why 
 files after "git add" has identical content but not commited anyway

Comment: Similar question is here, maybe some answers to find for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280719/git-precommit-maybe-with-help-phpstorm-and-php-cs-fixer

Answer (score 0):

In `pre-commit`, if you add some files by `git add`, those files will appear in files to commit.

The problem in your `pre-commit` is `[[ ${correction_code} -eq 1 ]]`.

When `php-cs-fixer fix` successed, it returns 0, not 1.

---

So, the `pre-commit` should be:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# get the list of changed files
staged_files=$(git diff --cached --name-only)

# build command to fix files
cmd='vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix %s -q'
if [ -f 'php_cs_fixer_rules.php' ]; then
    cmd='vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix %s -q --config=php_cs_fixer_rules.php'
fi

for staged in ${staged_files}; do
    # work only with existing files
    if [[ -f ${staged} && ${staged} == *.php ]]; then
        # use php-cs-fixer and get flag of correction
        "$cmd" "$staged" // execute php-cs-fixer directly
        correction_code=$? # if php-cs-fixer fix works, it returns 0

        # HERE, if returns 0, add stage it again
        if [[ ${correction_code} -eq 0 ]]; then
            git add "$staged" # execute git add directly
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0 # do commit
```